# Cannot set image from ParseCloud to ImageView

Tags: android, listview

So I've been following [this example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) to make a `ListView` with text and images (receiving the data from Parse Cloud) and the `ImageView` doesn't work.

I cannot set the image from the database to the `ImageView`. Rest of the data works fine, but the image is always one I've set as default.

OBS: On the tutorial I've seen that some people have had this problem and they manage to fix it by adding this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

to the `manifest`, assuming in the tutorial the data from the `cloud database` is saved on the phone so it won't be necessary to download it all the time. I've done this, didn't solve the problem.

EDIT: This is what I get in the log: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ParseListViewImgTxt/1929309245: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Is there any exception shown on the log? Or could you make sure that the image url is not empty?

Comment: As far as i understood, the url isn't null but it's wrong.